# How to convert a position of a pointer to int in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* s = "123456";
    
    int number = atoi(s[0]);
    
    printf("test %d",number);

    return 0;
}
```

I want it to print just the first character of my string as an integer, so I can use it in another algorithm. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why not just `printf("test %c", s[0])`?

Comment: If you actually want to convert it to an int, you can do `int number = s[0] - '0';`

Comment: @Iguananaut, I could, but I just want to learn how to convert a part of a pointer to an int

Comment: "part of a pointer"--what do you mean by "part of a pointer"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, that would return 49, which is the acii table decimal value for the char '1'

Comment: @CProgrammer  No, it would give `'1' - '0'` which is 1.

Comment: @stark, oh, I see! What is the '- '0'' for?

Comment: @Noob, If the string was `"qwe"`, what should "print just the first character of my string as an integer" print?  If string was `""`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `q` is a valid digit base36 for example. Isn't it?

Comment: @Noob  You already know '1' is 49.  So what is '0'?  What is '1' - '0'?  It's simple arithmetic.

Comment: @0___________ OK, perhaps I should ask Noob: If the string was "!@~", what should "print just the first character of my string as an integer" print?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica base is only limited by number of distinct printable chars. It greatly increases if we consider wchar. Then I can imagine "✓☒" number where ✓ is digit 32456

Comment: The `"123456"` string is referenced by a pointer, but it's not a pointer. `1` is not "part of a pointer"; it's the first byte of the string, sitting at the address where the pointer points.

Answer (score 1):

`s[0]` is already a signed char you can print it right away

```
printf("test %d", s[0]);    // test 49
```

or

```
int number = s[0];
printf("test %d", number);   // test 49
printf("test %d, %d, %d", s[0], s[1], s[2]);    // test 49, 50, 51
printf("test %c, %c", number, s[1]); // test 1, 2
```

Comment: it will print `49` for '1' not `1`. OP is not asking for it.